# Is it possible don't close popup in DatePicker on select date event

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

After I select date in DatePicker popup is closed.
I would like to close it manually with a button.
Can I prevent closing popup on date selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some time and playing around with, but I have succeeded in doing that you need. It will only **CLOSE** on button click, but it will open when clicking the Calendar button.

I added an `EventHandler` to the `DatePicker` when it was `hidden`.

```
VBox root = new VBox();
Button button = new Button("Click");
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
boolean[] buttonClicked = {false};
button.setOnAction(event->{
    if(datePicker.isShowing()) {
        buttonClicked[0] = true;
        datePicker.hide();
        buttonClicked[0] = false;
    }
});
datePicker.setOnHidden(event -> {
        if(!buttonClicked[0]){
            datePicker.show();
        }
    });
root.getChildren().addAll(button, datePicker);
Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,800); ////100,100 is width and height of window
//scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```